# Error when decrypt word, powerpoint file

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I'm using aes cryptography to encrypt file.

```
private static void Encrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        //int data;
                        //while ((data = fsInput.ReadByte()) != -1)
                        //{
                        //    cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
                        //}

                        byte[] bytes = new byte[fsInput.Length];
                        while (fsInput.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fsInput.Length) > 0) ;
                        cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Decrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        //int data;
                        //while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                        //{
                        //    fsOutput.WriteByte((byte)data);
                        //}
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[fsInput.Length];
                        while (cs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fsInput.Length) > 0) ;
                        fsOutput.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In main function i encrypt, decrypt word file:

```
Encrypt(@"E:\test.docx", @"E:\test.enc");
Decrypt(@"E:\test.enc", @"E:\test_new.docx");
```

When i use ReadByte function to encrypt, decrypt each byte. File test_new.docx is created and open normally. But when i use Read function to encrypt, decrypt many bytes, file test_new.docx is created but can't open, error content.
Any have ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that there are too many zeros at the end of the decrypted `bytes` array. This is because the used cipher requires each encrypted block to match the block size and if it doesn't fit it gets filled up. So `fsInput.Length` is actually bigger than length of the decrypted bytes.

To get rid of these zeros in the decrypted bytes replace this code in your `Decrypt` method

```
using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fsInput.Length];
    while (cs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fsInput.Length) > 0) ;
    fsOutput.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

with this code

```
using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
using (BinaryWriter fsDecrypted = new BinaryWriter(fsOutput))
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(cs))
    fsDecrypted.Write(br.ReadBytes((int)fsInput.Length));
```

Now it should work as expected.

Comment: The default padding is PKCS#7 `PaddingMode.PKCS7` not null padding. the [SymmetricAlgorithm Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm_properties.aspx) page on the MSDN. See the @Neil Humby answer.

Comment: @zaph You are absolutely right, I corrected my answer. But I think using a `BinaryReader` to read the contents all at once is still better performance-wise than using `ReadByte()` like Neil Humby suggested.

Comment: @zaph The zeros in the decrypted `bytes` don't come from PKCS#7 padding but from the `byte[] bytes = new byte[fsInput.Length];` because `fsInput.Length` is actually too big. I corrected my answer to reflect this aspect. Are there any more errors in my answer? (I'm willing to learn.)

Comment: Note that `fsInput.Length` is not known in the general case where encryption and decryption are separated in distance and time. If you specify the same padding option for encryption and decryption and call final on the last bytes being decrypted the decrypted data will match the plain data that was encrypted. No fiddling is needed. If a buffer was created larger than the the decrypted data truncate the buffer to the reported size of the decrypted data.

Comment: @haindl I have tested your code. It's work perfectly. ReadBytes function of BinaryReader return byte length exactly.

Comment: @user2637368 Glad I could help you.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong stream length for decryption, instead of fsInput.Length you should use cs.Length as that is the stream you are actually reading from. The lengths of the FileStream and the CryptoStream are not the same so you cannot interchange them. HOWEVER, CryptoStream is also non-seeking which means it cannot seek the end of the stream and using .Length will throw a NotImplementedException. So for a non-seeking stream like CryptoStream you will have to read one byte at a time using ReadByte() until the stream says it is done.

Comment: `new BinaryReader(cs).ReadBytes((int)fsInput.Length)` will read the correct amount of bytes at once. This should have far better performance than reading one byte at a time for typical file sizes of Office documents.

Comment: I use cs.Length but it throw exception, cs.Length can't access.

Comment: That is true. When i comparing between length of filestream after encrypting and before decrypt, it is difference. I want read many bytes to improve speed when ecrypt, decrypt large files. This bug only occur when ecrypt, decypt word, powerpoint file, others file working normally.

Answer (score 0):

I have added some bytes at the end before encrypt file. After decrypting byte array, I find to this bytes to get file length exactly.

Comment: You absolutely don't have to add these extra bytes if you would just use the 3 code lines from my answer. I tested my code and it works without any other modifications. (I don't know why it was downvoted once.)